# Update permission was denied on the object

Tags: sql, security

When I grant a specific user db_datawriter access to one of our databases, the permissions do not work.  I add the user's Active Directory account as a login, then map the user to the database.  I then log in as that user to SSMS and run an update query on a table.  This is the error I receive:
The UPDATE permission was denied on the object 'tblSGDTSXOnOff', database 'GPS_UAT0', schema 'dbo'.
If I try the exact same thing on a different user, it works fine.
I see no explicit Deny permissions for the user, so I'm at a loss as to what is going on.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

try giving both db_datareader and db_datawriter access.